# Obj C equivalent to Java StringTokenizer return delimiters

Tags: objective-c, string, stringtokenizer

I am trying to parse a large string in order to isolate words and all punctuation. Java has the following constructor for its StringTokenizer class.

```
public StringTokenizer(String str, String delim, boolean returnDelims)
```

Notice the last parameter. If that is true, each delimiter is also returned as a token.

Is there a class in Obj-C that mimics this Java functionality? I have been able to parse the string, but I lose my delimiters in the process and those delimiters determine what I do next.

According to the CFStringTokenizer reference, it tokenizes into "words, sentences, and paragraphs". I need more granularity than that.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: NSScanner may be a good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method of `NSString` and then `NSMutableArray` to insert the delimiters between the substrings:

```
NSString *s = @"abc,def,ghi,jkl";
NSString *delim = @",";

NSArray *arr = [s componentsSeparatedByString:delim];
NSMutableArray *res = [NSMutableArray array];

[res addObject:arr[0]];
for (NSInteger i = 1; i < arr.count; i++) {
    [res addObject:delim];
    [res addObject:arr[i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", res);
```

Comment: That would work for one delimiter, but I have nine that I am breaking on. If I am reading your code correctly, I have no way of knowing which delimiter caused the break. I may have to roll my own. Good opportunity to write a reusable helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample category on NSScanner that may get you started:

```
@implementation NSScanner (Tokenizer)

+ (NSArray *)tokenize(NSString *str,NSString *delim,BOOL returnDelims)
{
    NSScanner       *scanner=[NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    NSString        *delimiters=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@",.!;"];
    NSMutableArray  *ma=[NSMutableArray array];
    NSString        *s;

    while(![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        if([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:delim intoString:&s])
        {
            [ma addObject:s];
        }
        if([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:delim intoString:&s])
        {
            if(returnDelims) [ma addObject:s];
        }
    }

    return ma;
}

@end
```

This isn't a complete implementation, it doesn't deal with whitespace or enforcing a specific order in the array. But it should give you an idea.